# download gz file on clicking a url and convert to csv using scala

Tags: scala, csv, http, gzip, get-request

I am really messing with syntax here need help...

I have a URL, on clicking of which a sample.csv.gz file gets downloaded

Please can someone help me fill the syntactic gaps below:

```
val outputFile = "C:\\sampleNew" + ".csv"
val inputFile = "C:\\sample.csv.gz"
val fileUrl = "someSamplehttpUrl"

// On hitting this Url, sample.csv.gz file should download at destination 'outputFile'
val in = new URL()(fileUrl).openStream()
Files.copy(in, Paths.get(outputFile), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)

val filePath = new File(outputFile)
if(filePath.exists()) filePath.delete()
val fw = new FileWriter(outputFile, true)
var bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile)), "UTF-8"))
while (bf.ready()) fw.append(bf.readLine() + "\n")
```

I have been getting several errors with syntax... Any corrections here? I basically have an http get request that returns a URL, which I must open to download this gz file

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

```scala
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}
import scala.io.Source

val outputFile = "out.csv"
val inputFile = "/tmp/marks.csv"
val fileUrl = s"file:///$inputFile"

// Method 1, a traditional copy from the input to the output.
val in = Source.fromURL(fileUrl)
val out = new PrintWriter(outputFile)
for (line <- in.getLines)
  out.println(line)

out.close
in.close
```

Here is a one liner which basically pipes the data from the input to the output.

```scala
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL

val outputFile = "out.csv"
val inputFile = "/tmp/marks.csv"
val fileUrl = s"file:///$inputFile"

// Method 2, pipe the content of the URL to the output file.
new URL(fileUrl) #> new File(outputFile) !!
```

Here is a version using Files.copy

```scala
val outputFile = "out.csv"
val inputFile = "/tmp/marks.csv"
val fileUrl = s"file:///$inputFile"

import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, StandardCopyOption}
import java.net.URL

val in = new URL(fileUrl).openStream
val out = Paths.get(outputFile)

Files.copy(in, out, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Hopefully one (or more) of the above will address your needs.